# Is there an adjective that means "affect each other"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

I have a phrase "X and Y are systems that are dependent on each other and affect each other".

I want to rephrase this to "X and Y are interdependent and ???? systems"

Is there a suitable adjective? perhaps "mutually ???"

Comment: One might say two such systems are _codependent_. At least some people would.

Comment: dependent implies affect.  "X and Y are interdependent" is enough.

Comment: One could use *entwined* or *[entangled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/entangle)* thus, at the risk of perpetrating a metaphor from quantum physics.

Comment: interdependent works on its own, but if you want a synonym then maybe _linked_ or _affiliated_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was "interacting". This might not be the most suitable for all contexts, but worked best for me.

So "X and Y are interacting and interdependent systems"

Answer (score 1):

Corresponsive is a possibility. According to Merriam-webster, it means 'mutually responsive' which seems pretty close to what you are looking for.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corresponsive

Comment: Ill do that when I get a chance, but just for the record I cant make comments yet, otherwise this would have been one.

Comment: I think all of these only mean that they act together, not that they act on one another.

Comment: @HenryBrice I removed two of my suggestions that on second review, I agree with you about. Added a source for corresponsive, which think is a better answer.